# Change a css attributte from x to y over time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is my current code:

```
jQuery(function(){
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#cont').click(function(e){    
            $('#splashText').fadeOut(300, function(){
                $('#bgImage').animate('filter: blur(0px)', 300);
            });
        });
    });
})
```

I am trying to have `#splashText` fade out (which works fine), while at the same time `#bgImage` changes it's blur (set via `filter: blur(5px);`)from 5px to 0px with jQuery. Also, `#cont` is a button that is supposed to trigger the transition onclick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're doing is [passing a callback to `fadeOut`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/#fadeOut-duration-complete), which means that the `animate` function will be called after `fadeOut` completes its execution. Try this instead:

```
$('#cont').click(function(e){    
    $('#splashText').fadeOut(300);
    $('#bgImage').animate(...);  // Do you animation here
});
```

Also, you're using the `animate()` function wrong. [This is a good explanation on how you use blur filter in jquery animate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20082518/1492578). The relevant code:

```
$('#bgImage').animate({blurRadius: 10}, {
    duration: 500,
    easing: 'swing', // or "linear"
                     // use jQuery UI or Easing plugin for more options
    step: function() {
        $('#bgImage').css({
            "-webkit-filter": "blur("+this.blurRadius+"px)",
            "filter": "blur("+this.blurRadius+"px)"
        });
    }
});
```

```js
$(function() {
  $('#cont').click(function(e) {
    $('#splashText').fadeOut(600);
    $('#bgImage').animate({
      blurRadius: 5
    }, {
      duration: 600,
      easing: 'linear',
      // use jQuery UI or Easing plugin for more options
      step: function() {
        this.blurRadius = 5 - this.blurRadius;
        console.log(this.blurRadius);
        $('#bgImage').css({
          "-webkit-filter": "blur(" + this.blurRadius + "px)",
          "filter": "blur(" + this.blurRadius + "px)"
        });
      }
    });
  });

});
```

```css
#bgImage {
    filter: blur(5px);
    -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
    z-index:-1;
}
#cont {
    margin-left:200px;
}
* {
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="cont">Click</button>

<h1 id="splashText">Splash</h1>

<img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" id="bgImage"/>
```