# Using jQuery's animate with css filter.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to make the level of brightness of the page animate when a button is clicked. 
I need the value to make a change every time the button is clicked. Like this.

```
$(".brightness-minus").click(function() {
    if(b < 11){
    $(".settings-inner-bar").animate({width: "-=3.3vw"});
    b++;
    console.log(b);
    }
```

In the above code i am using the "-=" to animate the width each time. 
What i am trying to do is replicate this effect on this tag.

```
    -webkit-filter: brightness(1);
     filter: brightness(1);
```

I am trying to bring it down in increments of 0.02 at a time.

Because of the word "brightness" being there too it doesn't seem to work.

Does anyone know how I can change the value of this in the same way.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: if b < 11 sounds like you want to increment. Maybe you meant if b **>** 11?

Comment: Hello and thanks for responding! That part is only to make the inner bar not go out of the container its in. so if the bar is empty then the button will not work. This will stop users lowering the brightness below what i plan to set as the min.

Comment: Try running your code here: http://www.pythontutor.com

Comment: Thank you for that!

Comment: The best way to thank us is upvoting questions and answers you think are useful. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20082283/animate-css-blur-filter-in-jquery#20082518) excellent answer

You can use the `animate()` function on a variable with a numeric value and then call a function during every step and then assign the value from the variable to a css property. So instead of using the `-=` operator you would need to store the current brightness in a variable and subtract from that. I made a JSFiddle to demonstrate (used an image for demonstrating the brightness): https://jsfiddle.net/0ccgjgL8/1/

```
<button class="brightness-minus">
- minus
</button>

<div class="wrapper">
<img class="settings-inner-bar" src="http://lorempixel.com/output/technics-q-c-640-480-4.jpg" />
</div>
```

jQuery

```
var b = 0;
var currentBrightness = 1;
$(function(){
  $(".brightness-minus").click(function() {
    if(b < 11){

      $({brightness: currentBrightness}).animate({brightness: currentBrightness-0.10}, {
          duration: 500,
          easing: 'swing', // or "linear"
          step: function() {
              console.log(this.brightness);
              $(".settings-inner-bar").css({
                  "-webkit-filter": "brightness("+this.brightness+")",
                  "filter": "brightness("+this.brightness+")"
              });
              currentBrightness = this.brightness;
          }
      });
      b++;
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: WOW thats incredible! Thank you very much!

Comment: FYI guys another fix I found was putting a black div behind the container and reducing the opacity instead filter. Just in case someone comes across this looking for another solution. :)